# Target class controller does not exist - laravel 7

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-7

My Ajax:

```
$('#upload').change(function () {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]);
    var url = '/admin/upload/services';

    $.ajax({
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: form,
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');
          }
    });
});
```

My Route: [My Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M6Ut.png)

My Controller:
[My Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kticu.png)

My UploadService:
[My UploadService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiNaW.png)

My error:
[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EAw8.png)

Comment: Please, paste the actual source code into your question. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Share the source code in your `App\Http\Services\UploadService` file.

Comment: I hope `dd($request->file());` is for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Don't forget to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71347702/edit) and show us the actual *full* `500 HTTP` error stack trace.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa dd($request->file()); i want to see if i get data from my ajax

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [visit help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take tour to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. See also. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Your screenshot of *My error* shows results in the **Headers** tab of the Developer Tools window corresponding to the AJAX request. I'm most interested in the output of the **Response** TAB.

Comment: I edited the photo My Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "message": Target class controller
> `[App\\Http\\Controllers\\UploadController]` does not exist.",

It appears Laravel is failing to find your Controller. Try clearing complied files and let composer try to auto-discover relevant classes.

In your terminal run these two commands one after the other.

```sh
php artisan clear-compiled
```

```sh
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I edited the photo My Error

Comment: @NDH  It seems to have worked based on your edited *My error* screenshot.  Laravel has now been able to find the `store` method in the `UploadController`. Simply remove the `dd($request->file());` line of code in that method body. You can replace that line with a demo `return ["Chips", "Chicken"];`

Comment: why can't i use dd($request->file());? when i used it, i get 500 internal error :(

Comment: @NDH The [dd() function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-dd) dumps the given variables and ends the execution of the script:. If you **do not** want to halt the execution of your script, use the [`dump()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-dump) instead. I.e: `return dump($request);`

Comment: @NDH You may [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: what should i do to accept your answer?

Comment: @NDH I guess you have already accepted my answer.✌. Thank you. [how do I accept an answer on stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)